# How to add or not a control in a aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a page with a web user control, this one is quite heavy and he is used only if the application user have some rights. So he is set to `visible = false` in case of user can't use it.. But in this case the control is added to page even he is not visible.

The problem is the web user control is used really Rarely. So I would like to not include code if this is not necessary.
I feel I have to use the preinit state to add the web user control when it is necessary but I don't know how..
Any good idea? Thanks for help..

Comment: cant you just have a if .. else statement and not add the control if the user has no rights to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add it in the code behind with LoadControl, eg. put PlaceHolder on that aspx page and then load it from the code, like this

```
if (something)
{
  Control cnt = Page.LoadControl("UserControl.ascx");
  placeHolder1.Controls.Add(cnt);
}
```

Comment: OnInit. You can't do it in the pageload, because the control gets restored in the OnInit from the ViewState on Postbacks. If you do this in the OnLoad you will loose all values trough postbacks

Comment: Ok it's work, asp.net is like some magic.. Tx for all answers

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean with *quite heavy*? If it it time consuming because of its databinding, you should provide a `public function`(f.e. `BindData`) that is not called automatically from page_load but from the page when it is requested and the user is authorized to see.

Comment: You could do all timeconsuming stuff in this function, so only the control's markup has to be registered by asp.net and the control's viewstate will be maintained. If this is too much, try Antonio Bakula's answer, otherwise my solution is simplier and does not have negative side-effects of recreating/readding the control and avoids ViewState/Event-handling problems.